# Проблема с notepad++

Tags: php, notepad++

Здравствуйте! В notepad++ п рописал ссылку, в документе php,  после "echo". Объединил теги "<а>..." в двойные кавычки, а сам адрес - в одинарные. и тогда всё, что есть в документе, в кавычках, приобрело вид ссылок, хотя ими не являются, а браузер показывает ошибку, на счёт кавычек. В чём может быть проблема? до того, как поставил ссылку, всё отображалось нормально. Если не трудно подскажите подробнее, пожалуйста, какие настройки нужны для документа php и notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
echo "<a href='http://mylink/'>link text</a>";
```